# Icant get netmiko module in GNS3

Tags: gns3

Wwhen I add this command `pip3 install -U netmiko`

I got this error msg:

```
 "Collecting bcrypt
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/07/6a6f2047a9dc9d012b7b977e4041d37d078b76b44b7ee4daf331c1e6fb35/bcrypt-4.1.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-xh5824ko/bcrypt/setup.py", line 72
        print(f"    Python: {'.'.join(str(v) for v in sys.version_info[:3])}")
                                                                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xh5824ko/bcrypt/"
```

Bunch of command but no solution.